# Scoreboard Player First Join

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a scoreboard on my server that broadcasts a message to players who join the server for the first time, but I don't know what the scoreboard is. If you don't know what I'm talking about here's an example `/scoreboard objectives add join [MY PROBLEM]`

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an explanation on how to make something run once](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/questions/runonce)

basically what you want to do for the first time they join the server is

```
/tellraw @a[tag=!join] <your message here>
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!join] add join
```

in a repeating-chain.